# Unable to install LanguageTool 2.5 extension for LibreOffice 4.2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, java, software-installation, libreoffice, openoffice.org

I am not able to install `LanguageTool` extension for **LibreOffice**. Getting exception when I try to install it.

***p.s. Somebody says that the solution is installing `openoffice.org-java-common` package but Ubuntu 14.04 does not have this package in its repository.***

**System details:**

```
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

LibreOffice: 4.2 (4.2.3.3)

LanguageTool: 2.5

Java: Oracle JDK 1.8.0_05
```

---

**Exception message:**

[image: Exception message]

Comment: For me it help to only **change** the Java runtime environment (JRE) being configured in LibreOffice from 11.0.x to 1.8.x (both OpenJDK). Thanks everyone nevertheless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. First of all, the most important:

   `sudo apt-get install`**`libreoffice-java-common`**`java-common`
2. Go to LibreOffice `Options` menu, choose `Advanced` and be sure `Use Java runtime environment` is checked and a Java version is selected.
3. Now install your extension either by double-clicking on it in File Manager or by importing it in LibreOffice `Extension Manager` dialog.

Comment: thanks a lot; now it works for me. The critical package is `libreoffice-java-common` as you highlighted.

Comment: I think worth adding: at least with Ubuntu 16.04 and LanguageTool 4.2, you need Java 8, installable e.g. with apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless, and select Java 8 in LibreOffice. Java 7 won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error with 12.04, turned out java just wasn't enabled in LibreOffice. Might sound silly, but worth a check.

Go to Tools-Options-Advanced. I had the checkbox selected for "Use a java runtime environment", but right under that is "Java runtime environments(JRE) already installed:", and inside that list I hadn't selected anything.

Checked the Oracle 1.7, restarted LibreOffice, installed LanguageTool, all was well.

Comment: it is already detected and checked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using Kubuntu 18.10 and Java 11, the following solution worked for me:

1. Install the jaxb package: `sudo apt install libjaxb-java`
2. Open LibreOffice, and go to Tools -> Options -> Advanced
3. You should see the Oracle Corporation 11 JRE has been selected.
4. Select the Oracle Corporation 11 JRE, and click on Class Path.
5. Add /usr/share/java/jaxb-impl.jar

Restart LibreOffice, and the error should go away. I don't know what else is loaded, and haven't come across any other side effects yes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have OpenJDK Java runtime installed.  You can do so from the Ubuntu Software Center.  Once done, download the LanguageTool, and choose open with Libreoffice.  See image below

[image]

If you open writer, you will see it

[image]

[image]

As per your comments, I have installed Oracle Java, and tried installing LanguageTool, and I got the same error.  So I would assume that it will not work with Oracle Java.

Comment: can't I use with Oracle Java? because I need to use this vendor due to my other works.

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: as I declared in my first post, I have already Oracle Java 8.

Comment: See addition in my answer.