# Error when trying to install of LibreOffice language tool extension

Tags: software-installation, java, libreoffice

I got this error message when trying to install LibreOffice language tool in Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit.

```
(com.sun.star.uno.RuntimeException) { { Message = "[jni_uno bridge error] UNO calling Java method writeRegistryInfo: non-UNO exception occurred: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/star/task/XJobExecutor\X000ajava at stack trace:\X000at
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/star/task/XJobExecutor\X000a\X0009at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)\X000a\X0009at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:759)\X000a\X0009at 
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)\X000a\X0009at 
java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)\X000a\X0009at 
java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)\X000a\X0009at 
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)\X000a\X0009at 
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)\X000a\X0009at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\X000a\X0009at 
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)\X000a\X0009at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)\X000a\X0009at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)\X000a\X0009at 
java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:810)\X000a\X0009at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)\X000a\X0009at com.sun.star.comp.loader.RegistrationClassFinder.find(RegistrationClassFinder.java:52)\X000a\X0009at
 com.sun.star.comp.loader.JavaLoader.writeRegistryInfo(JavaLoader.java:399)\X000aCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.star.task.XJobExecutor\X000a\X0009at 
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)\X000a\X0009at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)\X000a\X0009at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)\X000a\X0009... 15 more\X000a", Context = (com.sun.star.uno.XInterface) @0 } }
```

Comment: The solution for this problem can be found here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/458240/unable-to-install-languagetool-2-5-extension-for-libreoffice-4-2-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 17):

this issue can be found here https://www.languagetool.org/issues/

you must install the package libreoffice-java-common or openoffice.org-java-common :

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-java-common
```

Comment: I have done this and now get a error = `The application cannot be started. 
[context="user"] caught unexpected com.sun.star.ucb.InteractiveAugmentedIOException: an error occurred during file opening` when I want to open any libreoffice file